# Запрос с опциональными OrderBy, Where и Take

Tags: c#, запрос, linq

Хочу сделать пагинацию с фильтром (любое условие) и сортировкой по любому полю.

Допустим, в сервисе мы будем принимать 4 параметра:

```
Task<List<UserResponse>> GetAllUsersAsync(int? skip = null,
    int? take = null,
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> wherePredicate = null,
    SortOptions<User> sortOptions = null);
```

где `UserResponse` - это DTO модель ответа, а `SortOptions<T>` - это вспомогательный класс, который в свою очередь хранит предикат для метода `OrderBy()` и тип сортировки:

```
public class SortOptions<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, object>> Predicate { private set; get; }
    public SortTypes SortType { private set; get; }

    public SortOptions(Expression<Func<T, object>> predicate, SortTypes sortType)
    {
        Predicate = predicate;
        SortType = sortType;
    }
}

public enum SortTypes
{
    ASC,
    DESC
}
```

Сам вопрос заключается в том, как правильно всё это реализовать, без 8 if'ов.
То есть, если `skip` параметр не указан, то LINQ запрос не изменится, так как от `.Skip(skip.GetValueOrDefault())` ничего не скипнет и выберет данные с 0 позиции. Но вот `.Take(null)` возьмёт ничего, вместо всего. Поэтому приходится `.Take()` не использовать при null, например:

```
if (take == null)
{
    _context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FullNameNormalized)
        .Skip(skip.GetValueOrDefault())
        ToListAsync();
}
else
{
    _context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FullNameNormalized)
        .Skip(skip.GetValueOrDefault())
        .Take(take.Value)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Так же есть `.OrderBy()` и `.OrderByDescending()` для ASC и DESC сортировки соответственно. `.Where()` тоже не укажешь с null. Вспоминая комбинаторику, имея 3 опциональных параметров с двумя состояниями, получаем 8 вариантов. В итоге получается подобная структура:

```
if (sortOptions.SortType == SortTypes.ASC)
{
    if (take == null)
    {
        if (wherePredicate == null)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (wherePredicate == null)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if (take == null)
    {
        if (wherePredicate == null)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (wherePredicate == null)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А знаете ли вы, что промежуточные запросы тоже можно сохранять в переменную? :-) Только тип надо явно указывать, `IQueryable<...>` вместо `var`

Comment: @PavelMayorov Знаю, но не представляю как можно использовать это вписать в данной ситуации.

Comment: [Why LINQ beats SQL](https://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx) - здесь немножко о том, что имеет в виду Pavel Mayorov.

Comment: Ну например так: `IQueryable<UserResponse> ordered = _context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.FullNameNormalized); IQueryable<UserResponse> orderedWithSkip = skip == null ? ordered : ordered.Skip(skip.Value); IQueryable<UserResponse> orderedWithSkipAndTake = take == null ? orderedWithSkip : orderedWithSkip.Take(take.Value);` и т. д. (Можно, конечно, и в одной переменной накапливать результат: `if (take != null) result = result.Take(take.Value);`, если хочется.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код можно существенно упростить следующим образом:

```
IQueryable<User> query = _context.Users;

if (skip != null)
    query = query.Skip(skip.Value);

if (take != null)
    query = query.Take(take.Value);

if (wherePredicate != null)
    query = query ...

// другие условия ...

return query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: `Skip()` и `Take()` нужно использовать в конце, а не в начале, чтобы сначала выбрать весь список по условию, а затем выбирать уже нужные позиции.

Answer (score -1):

Мой вариант с использованием `?:`

```
IQueryable<User> query = _context.Users;

query = wherePredicate != null ? query.Where(wherePredicate) : query;
query = sortOptions.Predicate == null ? query :
    sortOptions.SortType == SortTypes.ASC ? query.OrderBy(sortOptions.Predicate) : query.OrderByDescending(sortOptions.Predicate);
query = query.Skip(skip.GetValueOrDefault());
query = take != null ? query.Take(take.Value) : query;

List<User> users = await query.ToListAsync();
```